# Interpreting $\textbf{PA} + \neg\text{Con}(\textbf{PA})$ in $\textbf{PA}$

Tags: logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms

How does one [interpret](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743893/interpretation-of-one-theory-in-another) $\textbf{PA} + \neg\text{Con}(\textbf{PA})$ in $\textbf{PA}$, and what is the significance of such an aberrant interpretation?

I'm interested in the following: $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Inf}$ can be interpreted in $\textbf{PA}$, so I thought that any $\textbf{ZF}$-theorem in the language of $\textbf{PA}$ (under the translation) that is independent of $\textbf{PA}$ (such as Goodstein's) must necessarily involve some application of an infinite totality, that is $\textbf{Inf}$ must be used. Since otherwise it would be provable in $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Inf}$, and hence there would be a $\textbf{PA}$-proof of a sentence which "says" the same as Goodstein's sentence, at least in the sense that the original formulation is $\textbf{PA}$-equivalent to the there-and-back translated version. This is at least what my intuition tells me when I consider the Ackermann interpretation.

But I'm not completely sure what "says" really is here. My teacher said that interpretations do not have to preserve *meaning* and gave $\textbf{PA} + \neg\text{Con}(\textbf{PA})$ in $\textbf{PA}$ as an example. He also said that *"[my] reasoning assumes that any proof going beyond $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Inf}$ would involve infinity, but that's not obvious (for instance, there might be statements $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Inf}$ can't prove not because they involve Infinity but because involve instances of Separation that are not first-order definable)"*

I'm unsure about the meaning of both his points.

Comment: Someone care to explain the down vote...?

Comment: I mean, you're asking "please explain Godel's incompleteness theorem", which is a somewhat big topic for a single question.  (I'm not the down-voter)

Comment: @nomen No, that's not the question. "Interpretation" is a technical term.

Comment: @Jori Regarding the previous to last paragraph, $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is conservative over $\mathsf{PA}$ for arithmetic statements, and can discuss some infinite sets. To truly go beyond $\mathsf{ZF}-\mathsf{Inf}$ could in this sense be understood as meaning involving unpredicative sets.

Comment: @Andrés I'm not exactly sure how that relates to my question? For that part the teacher in question responded: "even though the statement is provable in ZF, it doesn't mean that it is not provable in a theory which goes beyond ZF-Inf but is, in some sense, finitistic. Of course, what such a theory would like is not clear at all. But the mathematics does not rule that out. (As an analogy, consider someone claiming that because CH isn't provable in ZFC but is provable in ZFC + V=L, then a proof of CH should make use of V=L."

Comment: @nomen To elaborate on Andres' comment, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)).

Comment: @Jori What I meant is that to go beyond the theory in question is more complicated than simply ``involving infinite sets'', since some such sets can be coded by finitistic (predicative) means. The paragraph ws not meant to be an answer to the paragraph but rather a word of caution.

Comment: @nomen Or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315451/462).

Comment: @Andrés OK, I see. I am investigating this connection between PA and ZF-Inf in relation to Isaacson's thesis. So what my question really is about is whether ZF-theorems that go beyond PA must involve the Inf axiom, in which case Isaacson's thesis is quite trivially true, for all those ZF theorems independent of PA at least (the higher-order resource is just Inf, and it _must_ be used). The fact that PA is able to code some infinitary reasoning itself, or is conservative over some theory that can directly speak about certain infinities, is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Btw, I mean absolutely no offense by that last sentence, your comments are highly valued by me. I'm just trying to sort out if I understand your point correctly or not ;) .

Comment: @Jon Yes, I think you understood correctly.

Comment: @Noah I'm talking about a proof-theoretic notation (as linked in the question), which is about theories, not models. But I guess that the notion of interpretation you linked to on Wikipedia relates like: $T_1$ proof-theoretically interprets $T_2$ iff for every $M \models T_2$ and $N \models T_1$ there exists an interpretation without parameters of $M$ in $N$. Or something like that ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, since it's more about the particular result that $\mathsf{PA} + \neg\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{PA}$. Still, I hope it is of some help.

This result was proved by Feferman in his important paper "[Arithmetization of Metamathematics in a General Setting](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm49/fm4915.pdf)" (it's theorem 6.5 in the paper). The notation in the paper is a bit heavy and old-fashioned, though, so it may take some time to get used to it. I'm not going to prove his result here, since the proof is rather laborious, but I do want to make some quick remarks about it.

(1) The first thing to note is that the result relies on the following fundamental point made in Feferman's paper, namely that some care must be taken when handling consistency statements (for an introductory treatment of the same point, cf. chapter 36 of Peter Smith's Gödels book). In particular, in that paper, Feferman constructs consistency statements *relative to a particular formula coding the theory*, and this may be relevant.

That is, if $T$ is a theory, then he roughly says that a formula $\alpha(x)$ of the language of arithmetic numerates the theory if for every sentence $\phi$ of the language of the theory, $\phi \in T$ iff $\mathsf{Q} \vdash \alpha(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, where $\mathsf{Q}$ is Robinson's arithmetic. If, moreover, $\alpha$ is such that if $\phi \not \in T$ iff $\mathsf{Q} \vdash \neg \alpha(\ulcorner \phi \urcorner)$, then $\alpha$ is said to bi-numerate the theory. (These notions correspond to what is generally called weakly represent and strongly represent, respectively.)

Anyway, the point is that consistency statements are relative to such bi-numerations, so that they are better expressed by Feferman's notation $\mathsf{Con}_\alpha(T)$. Indeed, by exploiting some coding tricks, Feferman shows (Theorem 5.9) roughly that if $T$ is a recursive consistent extension of $\mathsf{PA}$, then there is a rather strange bi-numeration $\alpha^*$ of $T$ such that $T \vdash \mathsf{Con}_{\alpha^*}(T)$. In particular (Corollary 5.10), there is a bi-numeration $\pi^*$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ such that $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \mathsf{Con}_{\pi^*}(\mathsf{PA})$.

As Feferman notes, this does not contradicts Gödel's theorem because these bi-numerations do not "properly express membership" in the given theory: "Indeed, inspection of the proof of 5.9 reveals that it expresses membership in a certain subsystem of [$T$] which, independent of the consistency of [$T$], is always consistent" (p. 69).

In fact, using a similar technique, Feferman also shows that, letting $\alpha$ be a bi-numeration of $\mathsf{PA}$ and setting $T=\mathsf{PA} + \neg \mathsf{Con}_\alpha(\mathsf{PA})$, there is a bi-numeration $\beta^*$ of $T$ such that $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \mathsf{Con}_{\beta^*}(T)$! (This is theorem 5.11.)

Using these results, Feferman then shows, first, that if $T$ is a theory and $\alpha$ is a numeration of $T$, then $T$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{PA} + \mathsf{Con}_\alpha(T)$ (theorem 6.2), which he then uses to prove (a result that implies) that there is a numeration $\alpha$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ such that $\mathsf{PA} + \neg \mathsf{Con}_\alpha(\mathsf{PA})$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{PA}$. The idea is roughly this, again using $T = \mathsf{PA} + \neg\mathsf{Con}_\alpha(\mathsf{PA})$:

By 5.11 there is a bi-numeration $\beta^*$ such that $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \mathsf{Con}_{\beta^*}(T)$. By 6.2, $T$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{PA} + \mathsf{Con}_{\beta^*}(T)$. But we have just seen that $\mathsf{PA} + \mathsf{Con}_{\beta^*}(T)$ just is $\mathsf{PA}$. Hence, the result follows.

(2) As Feferman notes, this roughly means that "we can construct a 'non-standard model' of [$\mathsf{PA}$] within [$\mathsf{PA}$] which, moreover, we can verify, axiom by axiom, to be a model of [$\mathsf{PA} + \neg\mathsf{Con}_{\beta^*}(\mathsf{PA})$]" (p. 77). Moreover, as he also observes in a footnote appended to this text, this is not all that surprising, given Gödel's theorems. The second incompleteness theorems basically states that, if $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, then so is $\mathsf{PA}$ extended with the negation of its consistency statement. Given that we generally use interpretations to prove relative consistency, this is basically a translation of that idea to relative consistency proofs.

---

**EDIT**: Well, I'm far from an expert on these questions, but here are my two cents (take these with lots of salt!):

First, it seems to me that there are two separate issues in the background of your question: (i) whether interpretation preserves meaning and (ii) whether the incompleteness of $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg \mathsf{Inf}$ is due to the negation of the axiom of infinity or some other limitation (the issue about arbitrary sets). Let's tackle these in order.

(i) It is true that just having an interpretation between theories is generally not sufficient to preserve "meaning", whatever that is. Indeed, one can have two theories being mutually interpretable without these interpretations preserving nice properties such as decidability, etc. Still, when two theories are mutually interpretable, perhaps the interpretations are of such a nature that we might as well identify the two theories. Here is a reasonable test. Suppose two theories, $T$ and $T'$, are mutually interpretable with interpretations $i: T \rightarrow T'$ and $j: T' \rightarrow T$. Suppose moreover that $i \circ j$ is the identity on $T'$ and $j \circ i$ is the identity on $T$, i.e. when I translate a formula using $i$, and then translate back using $j$, I always end up with the formula which I originally started (and vice-versa). When this situation takes place, say that the theories are *bi-interpretable*. Now, bi-interpretation *can* be reasonably taken to imply sameness of "meaning", since it preserves most of the interesting properties of the theories (technically, this is usually called synonymy, but the difference here is not relevant---cf. [this article by Friedman and Visser for more on the difference](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/308486/preprint320_1_.pdf?sequence=1)).

So, given this, what is the situation with $\mathsf{PA}$ and $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg\mathsf{Inf}$ (which I'll call in the sequel $\mathsf{ZF}_{\mathsf{Fin}}$)? These theories are mutually interpretable, but, disappoitingly, they are *not* bi-interpretable. In fact, they don't satisfy a weaker requirement of "sentential equivalence", as shown by Enayat, Schmerl, and Visser in "$\omega$-models of Finite Set Theory", theorem 5.1; the proof is not difficult, but it does use some facts about the model theory of $\mathsf{PA}$ (and of $\mathsf{ZF}_{\mathsf{Fin}}$).

On the other hand, there is a theory in the vicinity which *is* bi-interpretable with $\mathsf{PA}$, namely $\mathsf{ZF}_{\mathsf{Fin}} + \mathsf{TC}$, where $\mathsf{TC}$ is the axiom which states that every set is contained in a transitive set (cf. [this article by Kaye and Wong](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ndjfl/1193667707)). The issue is related to $\varepsilon$-induction: adding this axiom is essentially equivalent to adding $\varepsilon$-induction (see again the article by Kaye and Wong). So there is a very strong sense in which these two theories are the same.

(ii) On the other hand, there is the issue about whether the fact that $\mathsf{ZF}_{\mathsf{Fin}} + \mathsf{TC}$ cannot prove Goodstein's theorem is due to the absence of an axiom of infinity or something else. From what I understand, he's probably referring to the fact that first-order $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does not fully capture the idea of an arbitrary set (cf. [this article by Ferreirós for an analysis of the notion](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1309952318)). Now, I'm really out of my depth here, but I thought the issue arose only for *infinite* sets. Is there an hereditarily finite set that is not first-order definable? If not, then his complaint is mute. If, however, there are such sets, then he may be on to something.

Comment: Wait, doesn't this imply (5.11 & 6.2) that PA interprets any theory T?

Comment: @Jori Why? Note that $T = \mathsf{PA} + \neg\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ in 5.11

Comment: I see, I missed that. I already up-voted your excellent answer, and it is definitely good enough to accept. But maybe you're interested also in the background of my question (relating to Isaacson's thesis); there is a discussion between Andrés and me in the comment.

Comment: @Jori - I've edited the answer with some additional comments. I hope you fin these helpful.

Comment: I've been reading the Kaye-Wong paper (thanks!). But I don't quite get what they mean by: "At first, it appears difficult to see how to use $\in$-induction at all, since the required inductive definition of $p$ is $p(x) = \Sigma_{y\in x} 2^{p(y)}$ and this seems to need a separate induction on the cardinality of $x$—just the sort of induction we don’t yet have and are trying to justify. However, there is a way round this problem using ordinal summation." Any thoughts? I'm trying to recall the details of how much set theory we actually need to define a $p$ like this.

Comment: I've expanded on the above question, in case you are interested, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776663/epsilon-recursion-and-zf-inftc-in-the-inverse-ackermann-interpretation.