# Epsilon recursion and ZF-Inf+TC in the Inverse Ackermann Interpretation

Tags: logic, set-theory, proof-theory, peano-axioms

In the paper [On Interpretations of Arithmetic and Set Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1193667707) of Kaye and Wong they write:

> Equipped with $\in$-induction, we obtain an inverse interpretation of
> PA in ZF−Inf*. The plan is to define a natural bijection $p: V \to \text{On}$
> between the whole universe and the ordinals. The required
> interpretation can then be obtained by composing this map with the map
> $o$ defined on $\text{On}$. At first, it appears difficult to see how
> to use $\in$-induction at all, since the required inductive definition
> of $p$ is $p(x) = \sum_{y\in x} \, 2^{p(y)}$ and this seems to need a
> separate induction on the cardinality of $x$ —- just the sort of
> induction we don’t yet have and are trying to justify. However, there
> is a way round this problem using ordinal summation.

Here ZF−Inf* is ZF plus the negation of Inf in addition to the axiom TC, which says that every set is contained in a transitive closure.

I don't understand the point the authors are trying to make here. Specifically:

1. Can't we just define $p(x) = \sum_{y\in x} \, 2^{p(y)}$ using $\in$-induction in ZF-Inf*?
2. What do they mean by *"this seems to need a separate induction on the cardinality of x —- just the sort of induction we don’t yet have and are trying to justify."* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. How can you define the summation over $x$? We have not defined the notion of summation over a given set, even when the set is finite. We finally lead to the definition of Kaye and Wong, when we tried to define the summation over $x$ formally.
2. Kaye and Wong defined their sum by using set induction on $x$. They suggested that it is likely to define their sum ranged over a finite set $x$ by induction on *the size of $x$*. (They did not follow it, however.)
   Our usual sum notation $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$ only cares the number of terms, not the set of range. It could be the reason why they mention this sentence.

Comment: Ah, I see, and induction on size is precisely what we cannot do because we don't have Inf. While in ZF-Inf* we do still have ordinal recursion . Is that it?

Comment: @Jori There is no notion of size in their article. It would be tedious work, although it could be not hard to define even without the axiom of infinity. I believe this is the reason why they choose set induction instead (this is an axiom, which we can use without any further verification!)

Comment: I wouldn't know how induction on size would look like without Inf?

Comment: @Jori I think the following works (although we need to check details): if Inf holds, then we can use the usual induction argument. If the negation of Inf holds, then we can show that every set is finite. Now we can use the induction on the size of sets, which is in fact the induction on natural numbers.

Comment: @HanulJeon But how do you use induction in the natural numbers without the axiom of infinity?

Comment: @Nagase The induction scheme for ordinals is still provable even if we do not have the axiom of infinity ($\in$-induction is sufficient to prove it.) If the negation of infinity holds, then I *believe* the class of all ordinals is the class of natural numbers. (There is a way to get around this belief, but it is more lengthy to explain.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, the class of ordinals is the class of the natural numbers, but how does one prove that *inside* the theory? In fact, it is not even clear how to define the class of natural numbers with the axiom of infinity negated...

Comment: Nagase, we can define a natural number to be the $x$ such that $\forall y(y\in x\lor x=y\rightarrow y=0\lor y\text{ is a successor ordinal})$. Obviously this definition still holds even when we have the axiom of infinity.

Comment: So we can prove the induction on natural numbers without the axiom of infinity.

Comment: @WerlopRop - Isn't that basically the definition of "$x$ is an ordinal"?

Comment: @Nagase It excludes the case when $x$ contains a limit ordinal.

Comment: @HanulJeon - But isn't that case excluded automatically when we are working in $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}^*$?

Comment: @Nagase No problem, you can show that every ordinal is either successor or limit (or 0) without any help of the axiom of infinity.

Comment: @HanulJeon - Yes, I'm aware of that. What I'm saying is this: we can prove that every ordinal is either successor or limit or 0. But we can also prove that no ordinal is a limit. So we prove that every ordinal is either a successor or 0. Hence the proposed definition is just defining the ordinals.

Comment: @Nagase Then we may define $\omega$ as the collection of all ordinals when the negation of infinity holds. It might not be satisfactory, though.

Comment: The other definition I can suggest is the following (due to Aczel and Rathjen): $x\in\omega$ iff there is a transitive set $a$ such that for each $y\in a$, either $y=0$ or $y$ is a successor of another set, and $x\in a$. (Note that $a$ need not be closed under the successor operation.)

Comment: @HanulJeon - Right. But then induction on natural numbers just is induction on the ordinals, so we are back to the route taken by Kaye and Wong in the paper.

Comment: Nagase, if we can prove in $ZF-\mathsf{Inf}$ that the above definition I gave is equivalent to that of ordinals, then $ZF-\mathsf{Inf}\vdash\lnot\mathsf{Inf}$, which would imply $ZF$ is inconsistent. So whenever you assume the consistency of $ZF$, you cannot prove in $ZF-\mathsf{Inf}$ that there is no limit ordinal which is not 0

Comment: @WerlopRop - No, no. $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}^*$ is not here $\mathsf{ZF}$ without the axiom of infinity, but rather $\mathsf{ZF}$ plus the *negation* of the axiom of infinity plus the axiom which states that every set is contained in a transitive set. See the paper for details. (I know the terminology is confusing; I prefer to call the theory $\mathsf{ZF}_{\mathsf{Fin}}^*$ to avoid confusion, but that's not the terminology of the paper)

Comment: Nagase: oh ok. Your frist question is "But how do you use induction in the natural numbers without the axiom of infinity?", so I was confused...

Comment: @WerlopRop - Ah, I see. I meant that it was not obvious how to formulate induction in the natural numbers without *using* the axiom of infinity because the theory asserts its negation, but I can see how that could be interpreted as "because the theory lacks the relevant axiom". Sorry for that.

Comment: Nagase, what is your real question? Is it "how does one prove inside $ZF−\mathsf{Inf}+\lnot\mathsf{Inf}$ that the class of all ordinals is the class of natural numbers?"? I think it depends on the definition of natural numbers in $ZF-\mathsf{Inf}$. Inside this theory, the natural numbers can be introduced as I gave, so this definition is just that of ordinals in the theory plus $\lnot\mathsf{Inf}$. So? We just think all ordinals as natural numbers inside that.

Comment: @WerlopRop - I'm trying to understand K&W's comment. They say that they cannot define the relevant expression using induction on the size of the sets, which in this case seems to be induction on the natural numbers. And the reason they can't define the relevant expression using induction on the size of the sets is because, according to them, this type of induction is not available in the theory. So, either induction on the natural numbers is not induction on the size of sets, or else it is not available in the theory, or else K&W made a blunder.

Comment: @Nagase I'm not sure what the issue is here. Take the following example: let $S \subset \omega$ be finite; the formula that expresses the cumulative sum of $S$ is defined by the recursion theorem (for natural numbers), which requires induction. And the situation above is very similar to this. But in this case we can get away by cleverly rephrasing it as an ordinal recursion. Or am I missing something?